# looping node array of asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Below code is node giving undefined how to get console.log from an array containing asynchronous functions. I tried promises still I  could not

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path")
var req = {},
  res = {},
  previous = {};
var reqOBj = [];
var use = function(fun) {
  reqOBj.push(fun)
}
use(function(req, res, previous) {
  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "/index.html"), "utf8", function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return previous;
    }
  })
})
use(function(req, res, previous) {
  previous.mid = '2nd';
  return previous;
})
for (let index = 0; index < reqOBj.length; index++) {
  console.log(reqOBj[index](req, res, previous));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the functions in `reqOBj` to functions that return promises, and then `await` the resolution of the promises in the loop at the bottom:

```
use(function(req, res, previous){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname , "/index.html"), "utf8", function(err, data){
      if(err) reject();
      else resolve(previous)
    });
  });
});
use(function(req, res, previous){
  previous.mid = '2nd';
  return previous;
});
(async () => {
  for (let index = 0; index < reqOBj.length; index++) {
    console.log (await reqOBj[index](req, res, previous));
  }
})();
```

Comment: i am getting this err    (node:12636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: reqOBj is not defined
(node:12636) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you defined `reqOBj` at the top of your script...

Comment: how to do you think i should handle it

Comment: Sounds like either you didn't post the original code faithfully, or you pasted in the new code incorrectly. The snippet I posted should replace everything below your declaration of `use`.

Comment: ccode testing i did like this https://github.com/adbilagi/stack_test/blob/master/index.html

Comment: code testing i did like this https://github.com/adbilagi/stack_test/blob/master/index.html